# Return last value in a row, based on another cell value on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

anyone know a simple trick to automatically get the last value of the row in total assets on the first row each time ? I'd also lie to use the same trick for total liabilities later.

screenshot of what total assets looks like:

[image]

screenshot of other sheet:

[image]

I'm trying to get the value based on the value within the first column "Total Assets" on another sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is an easier way but you could do:

[image]

Formula in cell K4 is:

`=VLOOKUP($A$2;2:2;LOOKUP(2;1/(1:1<>"");COLUMN(1:1));FALSE)`

> **All credits to**: [Get value of last non-empty
> cell](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell)

Actually, if we add extra columns, the formula updates correctly:

[image]

**NOTE:** This formula works because headers row (row 1) holds just the headers. If there is any other cell with data outside this dataset, it won't work properly. Something like below would calculate the wrong output:

[image]

Comment: Very Nice! `LOOKUP()` within `VLOOKUP()` Function!